# is there a way for a person to select fields if they do not want all the fields but only certain fields

Tags: php, mysql

is there a way for a person to select fields from MYSQl,  if you only know the name of 5 fields while there are 10 fields but you only want the other 5 fields to which you do not know the names of the fields ?

is there a way a person can say select * except "the names of the fields you know".

Comment: We don't encourage Hacking :)

Comment: Why is that hacking? If you can `SELECT *` then what the question is asking is legitimate. Of course the answer is no, but it's still a legitimate question.

Comment: No , i have a system where users can add fields dynamically through a user interface where they can specify the field name they would like to add with the value . the problem is that i will not know the field name the user adds so i just want to say that do not select the fields names i know but only select the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM `tablename` WHERE FIELD NOT IN ('f1','f2','f3');
```

Execute this query and fetch the specific field-names and put each field-name into an array. then implode the array with ',' inside the select query.

```
$fields = implode(',',$fields_arr);
$sql = SELECT $fields FROM `tablename`;
```

Comment: do i start with  "$fields_arr = SHOW FIELDS FROM `tablename` WHERE FIELD NOT IN ('f1','f2','f3');"

Answer (score 0):

I know there are ways to do this by first finding all field names and excluding the ones you know of etc, but if the question is:

> Can I do `SELECT *(Except F1,F2,F3...) FROM....`

then the answer is no, SQL does not support what you are asking for. You have to explicitly specify what you want in the result set.